# Join 2 VB type files into VB file get an error (INVALID DATA SET ATTRIBUTES: SORTOUT BLKSIZE - REASON CODE IS 06) JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

Im trying to join 2 VB files into new VB files , but i always get this error "INVALID DATA SET ATTRIBUTES: SORTOUT  BLKSIZE - REASON CODE IS 06"

here's the code im writing right now

```
 //STEP2 EXEC PGM=SORT                                     
 //SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=A                                      
 //SORTJNF1 DD DSN=EHASNAW.DATA.DPDARPG1.FILTER,DISP=SHR     -> VB FILES 
 //SORTJNF2 DD DSN=EHASNAW.MEMO.REGGH.GDG.G0009V00,DISP=SHR   -> VB FILES
 //SORTOUT DD DSN=EHASNAW.DATASET.DPDARPG4,UNIT=SYSDA,     
 //             DCB=(RECFM=VB,BUFNO=40,BLKSIZE=0),         
 //             DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),                      
 //             SPACE=(CYL,(8,10),RLSE)                    
 //SYSIN DD *                                              
   JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(114,06,A)      -> already +4 for the position because its VB                
   JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(09,06,A)       -> already +4 for the position because its VB                
   REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:114,06)                             
   OUTREC FIELDS=(04,06)                                   
   SORT FIELDS=(04,06,PD,A)
```

anyone can help me? because i dont know whats wrong and im new to this language , thank you

Comment: Have you tried omitting the BLKSIZE from SORTOUT?

Comment: What are the dataset attributes of the two VB datasets you are trying to combine ?   LRECL, BLKSIZE, RECFM (I assume VB but just checking)

Answer (score 1):

Error message on z/OS are most always prefixed with a message identifier (3-4 alpha characters followed by 2-5 digits, optionally followed by another alpha character). This is the key to look up more information what the message wants to tell you.

In your case I bet the message identifier is "ICE043A". The easiest way to find the message explanation is to "Google" the identifier (not the complete message) Usually one of the top hits is the one you need.

Very often, the message has one or more additional information, such as "reason code", or "return code", etc. This then points to subsection within that message text with more detailed information what exactly happened.

In your case this additional information is "Rescon Code 06". If you look up the message, this subsection is takling about *fixed length record*, and problems with LRECL and BLKSIZE.

You specify RECFM=VB on your //SORTOUT DD statement but are building a fixed length record

```
...
OUTREC FIELDS=(04,06)
```

This somehow confuses SORTs logic to determine the output data sets attributes.
Leave away all output data set attributes and let SORT decide, or build a correct RECFM=VB record on your OUTREC (Hint: You must include the RDW, i.e. position 1-4).

You might not be used to get more details on error messages, but on z/OS (and z/VM for what it matters), this is the basics to go after errors. Most products do an excellent job in helping you with error message. So, whenever you're hit by a message that you don't understand, your first step should be to look up the message text. Very often, but not always, it can clearly tell what the problem is.